# proving Green's Theorem in the plane

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I would like someone to check my proof for Green's Theorem in the plane. Thank you.

### Definitions

We say a domain $A\in \mathbb{R}^2$ is Type 1 if there are some $ \ a,b\in R$ and  some continuous,  $\alpha,\beta:[a,b]\to R\ $, differentiable at any $x\in (a,b)$with $\alpha',\beta'$ piecewise uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$  s.t.  $$ A= \{ (x,y): a\le x\le b,\alpha(x)\le y\le \beta(x) \}. $$
Similarly, $A$ is Type 2 if  there are some $c,d\in R$ and continuous $\lambda,\eta: [c,d]\to R,$ with $ \lambda',\eta'$ differentiable at any $y\in (c,d)$ and $\lambda',\eta'$ piecewise uniformly continuous on $(c,d)$ s.t. $$ A=\{(x,y): c\le y \le d,\  \lambda(y)\le x \le \eta(y)\} .$$

### Lemma

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ an open set that is also a Type 1 domain. Given a differentiable function $f:\Omega\to R$, with continuous partial derivatives, the following holds: 
$$ \int_ A D_2f(x)\,dx=\int_{a}^{b}f(t,\beta(t))dt- \int_{a}^{b} f(t,\alpha(t))dt$$
where $D_2f$ is the partial derivative with respect to $y$.

**Proof**

1. As $\alpha',\beta'$ are piecewise,uniformly continuous on $(a,b)$, we can extend them to continuous functions on $[a,b]$ and ''break'' them into n piecewise continuous functions on closed and bdd. subintervals  $I_i$ of $[a,b]$ with $i\in{1,2, ... ,n}$ .
   Define the indicator functions $\chi_i(x) $ on each $I_i$. These have all a negligible boundary, as they are curves traced by  a $C^1$ curve, so their union has a negligible boundary, so it makes sense to speak of $\int_A D_2f(x)dx= \int_{a}^{b}D_2f(x)\cdot \chi_A(x)dx.$ In other words, being simple implies a negligible boundary ( is this correct?)
2. Now, I want to apply Fubini's Theorem. First, I need to make sure that the map $g:[a,b]\to \mathbb{R}$, $t\to \int_{\alpha(t)}^{\beta(t)} f(t,s)ds$ is continuous ( integrable).
   As $\alpha,\beta$ are continuous, I can write $g(t+\delta)-g(t)= \int_{\alpha(t)}^{\beta(t+\delta)} D_2f(t,s)ds- \int_{\alpha(t)}^{\beta(t)} D_2f(t,s)ds= \int_{\beta(t)}^{\beta(t+\delta)} D_2f(t,s)ds \le      
   M \cdot[(\beta(t+\delta)-\beta(t)], $

which I can control, as $\beta$ is continuous, so $g$ is continuous.
$ M $ is an upper bound for $D_2f$

3. Apply Fubini and FUndamental THeorem of calculus, and we're done.
4. Similar for a Type 2 domain.
5. Write $V= U+ W$, where $U^2=0$ and $W^1=0$ and apply the lemmas for type 1 and type 2 domains.

Also, I do not understand why this is:
'' Note that while the condition of being simple (both Type 1 and Type 2) is not by itself sufficient to ensure that $∂A$ is piecewise $C^1$''. Isn't this just by definition?